# Adding dynamic play button to HTML video

Tags: html, css

I'd like to add a dynamic play button to an HTML video that changes color when the video is moused over, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKU4W.jpg

and disappears once the video starts to play.

Any idea how I can set that up?

Comment: CSS `:hover` and JS `onPlay` event

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:hover` css property:

```css
.container{margin:50px;}
.fa-youtube-play{transform: scale(5);color:black;opacity:0.7;}
.fa-youtube-play:hover{transform: scale(5);color:dodgerblue;}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>
</div>
```

... and to make it disappear on click ...

```js
$('.fa-youtube-play').click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.container{margin:50px;}
.fa-youtube-play{transform: scale(5);color:black;opacity:0.7;}
.fa-youtube-play:hover{transform: scale(5);color:dodgerblue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>
</div>
```